# xargs not working in Linux as it works in Unix

Tags: xargs

I am using following command to list down permission, owner of mount points in unix:

```
bdf|awk '{print $6}'|grep -v Mounted|xargs ll -d
```

This command in HP-Ux provides me an output like below:

```
drwxr--r--  61 root       root          8192 Jan  1 2014 /
drwxr--r--  102 root       root          8192 Jan  1 2014 /home
```

But in Linux this command :

```
df -hP|grep -v Mounted|awk '{print $6}'|xargs 'll -d'
```

gives an error:

```
xargs: ll -d: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of the error is that you have quoted `ll -d` in the arguments to xargs.  `xargs` is then trying to execute a file called `ll -d` which it can't find anywhere on your path.  If you remove the quotes, the command is likely to work.  However, if `ll` is an alias rather than a command on the PATH, you may also need to use `ls` directly:

```
df -hP | grep -v Mounted | awk '{print $6}' | xargs ls -ld
```

If you have mount points that include spaces, your parsing of `df` would fail to account for that.

Comment: no need for grep here since awk is being used anyway.  e.g. `awk 'NR>1 {print $6}'` or `awk '!/Mounted/ {print $6}'`